# Why are $\mathfrak{pgl}_n\simeq\mathfrak{sl}_n$ when characteristic does not divide $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Suppose $k$ is some algebraically closed field whose characteristic does not divide $n$. Why can we identify the lie algebras $\mathfrak{pgl}_n\simeq\mathfrak{sl_n}$ of the projective linear group and special linear group?

I know 
$$
\operatorname{Lie}(PGL_n)\simeq\operatorname{Lie}(GL_n)/\operatorname{Lie}(Z(GL_n))\simeq\mathfrak{gl}_n/\{cI_n:c\in k\}
$$

but I'm having trouble seeing why this last quotient is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, and why $\operatorname{char}(k)\nmid n$ is needed. This came up while looking at the structure of $PGL_2$ to study $1$-dimensional semisimple algebraic groups.

Comment: Hint: The scalar matrices and those with trace $0$ intersect trivially, so you get a direct sum.

Comment: Note that Tobias Kildetoft's observation requires $\mathrm{char}(k)\nmid n$ since otherwise the identity matrix has trace $0$.